# Linked list does not add element in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm wring my linked list implementation in C and I am facing the problem that linked list doest not add elements to itself.  It only prints the first element.
Something is wrong here and I can't figure out what.
I managed to localize the problem that first element next field is always NULL no matter what I do. All the other things are legal. I add the results of the running at the end.

Here is linked list declaration:

```
    typedef struct list_element {
    int value;
    struct list_element *next;
} list_element;
```

Here is usage:

```
void checkLinkedList()
{
    list_element list = createNewLinkedList();
    list.value = 100;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {            
        printf("added another\n");

        int value = rand();
        insertNewElementAtEndWithValue(list, value);
    }
}

void insertNewElementAtEndWithValue(list_element element, int value)
{       
    printf("Starting element address: %p\n", &element);

    list_element *myElement = &element;       
    int shouldContinue = 1;

    while (shouldContinue) {            
        if (myElement->next == NULL) {
            printf("next is null, value is %d \n", value);

            list_element *new = (list_element *)malloc(sizeof(list_element));
            printf("new address %p\n", new);
            new->value = value;
            new->next = NULL;
            myElement->next = new;
            printf("New is: %p, myElement->next is: %p\n", new, myElement->next);
            shouldContinue = 0;
        } else {
            printf("Proceeding to next");
            myElement = myElement->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
./main

added another
Starting element address: 0x7fff5c10aac0
next is null, value is 16807 
new address 0x7fa3d3504b60
New is: 0x7fa3d3504b60, myElement->next is: 0x7fa3d3504b60
added another
Starting element address: 0x7fff5c10aac0
next is null, value is 282475249 
new address 0x7fa3d3504b70
New is: 0x7fa3d3504b70, myElement->next is: 0x7fa3d3504b70
added another
Starting element address: 0x7fff5c10aac0
next is null, value is 1622650073 
new address 0x7fa3d3504b80
New is: 0x7fa3d3504b80, myElement->next is: 0x7fa3d3504b80
added another
Starting element address: 0x7fff5c10aac0
next is null, value is 984943658 
new address 0x7fa3d3504b90
New is: 0x7fa3d3504b90, myElement->next is: 0x7fa3d3504b90
added another
Starting element address: 0x7fff5c10aac0
next is null, value is 1144108930 
new address 0x7fa3d3504ba0
New is: 0x7fa3d3504ba0, myElement->next is: 0x7fa3d3504ba0
added another
Starting element address: 0x7fff5c10aac0
next is null, value is 470211272 
new address 0x7fa3d3504bb0
New is: 0x7fa3d3504bb0, myElement->next is: 0x7fa3d3504bb0
added another
Starting element address: 0x7fff5c10aac0
next is null, value is 101027544 
new address 0x7fa3d3504bc0
New is: 0x7fa3d3504bc0, myElement->next is: 0x7fa3d3504bc0
added another
Starting element address: 0x7fff5c10aac0
next is null, value is 1457850878 
new address 0x7fa3d3504bd0
New is: 0x7fa3d3504bd0, myElement->next is: 0x7fa3d3504bd0
added another
Starting element address: 0x7fff5c10aac0
next is null, value is 1458777923 
new address 0x7fa3d3504be0
New is: 0x7fa3d3504be0, myElement->next is: 0x7fa3d3504be0
Number of elements in list: 1
 100,
```

Comment: Hint: C has "pass by value" semantics.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks, changed argument to pointer and it worked.

Comment: @Dvole also, [do not cast `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and always check the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: I expanded my comment into an answer for completeness.

Comment: I would suggest using 2 more pointers in the list data structure: 1. head element, always points at the first element; 2. tail element, which always points at the last element; it makes the time complexity O(1) in every case except when deleting the last but one element (you need to fix the tail pointer, find it iteratively/recursively - O(n)). In the case of insertion, you simply add at the end and, again, fix the tail pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that C has pass by value semantics, so in the body of this function

```
void insertNewElementAtEndWithValue(list_element element, int value) {...}
```

both `element` and `value` are local copies of the arguments.

In your case, you intend to modify the first argument, for which you need referential semantics. This can be achieved by using a pointer instead:

```
void insertNewElementAtEndWithValue(list_element* element, int value)
{
  /* as before except element is a pointer */
}
```

Comment: Just for the sake of information, I used to do this by returning the new list head and assigning that in the caller. Different approach, same result.

Comment: @SukkoPera That's a very good point. It makes the semantics of the function clearer and in fact my preferred way of doing things.